# How to paginate item

Tags: python, django

How do i paginate item in category. I have a category name men_clothing_shirt, i want to paginate all item on the template. The problem is when i change the paginator to 1, it displayed all item on one page instead of just displaying only one item on one page. When i click on the next button it takes me to page2 but all items still display there. The paginator do not paginate the item accordingly to the page. See uploaded images.

[image]

[image]

```
def men_shirt(request):
queryset_list = Category.objects.filter(name='man_clothing_shirt')  
paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 1)
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    queryset = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    queryset = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
context = {
'menshirtpaginator': queryset,
}
return render(request,'men_shirt.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs only the method `paginator.get_page()` raises the exceptions you are using try-except on, so instead of `paginator.page()` write `paginator.get_page()` everywhere in the view and try source: [Paginator methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/paginator/#methods)

```
def men_shirt(request):
    queryset_list = Category.objects.filter(name='man_clothing_shirt')  
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        queryset = paginator.get_page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        queryset = paginator.get_page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        queryset = paginator.get_page(paginator.num_pages)
    context = {
    'menshirtpaginator': queryset,
    }
    return render(request,'men_shirt.html', context)
```

Comment: When I added get_page to views, the paginator number in template disappear. @Sammy J

Comment: I think the problem has to do with the filter, when I change it o Category objects.all() the pagination works properly but I want to do it on filter because I'm filtering a category name in Category model.